# Proof of $H,G/H$ compact then $G$ compact by ideal where $H\leq G$ and $G$ is topological group

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory

Let $G$ be a topological group and $H\leq G$ be a subgroup.

If $H,\frac{G}{H}$ are compact, then $G$ is compact.

There is a step in the book I do not understand.

Denote $O(G)$ the collection of all open sets of $G$ and this forms a lattice. Let $J$ be an $O(G)$ ideal s.t. $\cup_{x\in J}x=G$. It suffices to show $G\in J$.

Definition of lattice: $X$ is a topological space and $S$ is a collection of set s.t. $\emptyset\in S,X\in S$ and $S$ is closed under intersection and union. Then $S$ is called lattice. In this case $O(G)$ is a lattice.

Definition of ideal $I$ of a lattice $O(G)$: $I$ is an ideal if $A,B\in I$ then $A\cup B\in I$ and if $A\in I, B\in O(G)$ and $B\subset A$, then $B\in I$.

For any $x\in G, xH$ is compact and $xH$ is covered by some element of $J$. So $xH\subset J$ with $J'\in J$. Now pick open neighborhood $V$ of identity element $e$ s.t $VxH\subset J'$. This gives $VxH\in J$ and this is union of cosets of $H$. Let $I=\{A\in O(\frac{G}{H})\vert \pi^{-1}A\cap V\in J\}$ where $\pi:G\to\frac{G}{H}$. It is clear that $I$ is an non-empty ideal of $O(\frac{G}{H})$. Now $\pi(VxH)\ni\pi(x)$. So $\pi(x)\in\cup_{x\in I}I$. Since $x$ is arbitrary, we have all $\pi(G)\subset\cup_{x\in I}I$. However $\pi(G)=\frac{G}{H}$ is compact. Hence $\pi(G)\in I$ by $I$ being ideal.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Then the book says "i.e. $G\in J$ and hence $G$ is compact". Why so?

Ref: Introduction to Topological Groups by Higgins.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what an $O(G)$ ideal is, however I do know that there  are easier proofs of this fact if you are interested in that.

Comment: @SheelStueber The point of understanding this proof is to understand the proof of $H,\frac{G}{H}$ locally compact implying $G$ locally compact. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(order_theory)

Comment: @SheelStueber I think I understood why the book says so.

Comment: @SheelStueber I have added definition of lattice and ideal.

Comment: There appear to be several typos in what you have written.  In particular, I'm pretty sure your definition of $I$ is badly incorrect.

Comment: In any case, which part do you not understand: the conclusion that $G\in J$, or how this implies that $G$ is compact?

Comment: @EricWofsey There are 2 questions. 1. I do not see why I need to pick $I$ ideal s.t. $I$ has elements intersecting with $V$ in $J$. I feel $V$ is more or less redundant here. Correct me if I am wrong. 2. How this implies $G$ compact? Do I just pick representatives from cosets defined by open set $VxH$ via projection map? I think I copied the definition of ideal correctly from the book or was there mistakes? Thanks.

Comment: The proof with the definition of $I$ as written makes no sense and is obviously incorrect.  If you correctly copied the definition from the book, then there must be some sort of typo in the definition in the book.

Comment: @EricWofsey In my thought process is to pick out $VxH$ representative by running $x$ through all representatives in the quotient target. This will give a whole left coset decompostion of $G$ which shows $G$ is covered by finite number of those representatives. Is this correct? If there is typo in the book, then I do not see how to proceed to prove corresponding statement for locally compact setting. Can you provide some source that works for both compact and locally compact setting? Thanks.